# what is the postback from input type=image

Tags: php, forms

hi I have an input with the type  equal to image and I am trying to get check the postback. if the type is submit then I just check the name what do I check for the image?

```
<input type="image" src="somehting.jpg" alt="Buy Now" title=" Buy Now " id="addPartBtn">

else if($_POST['?']{
```

I put a question mark in the code where im nto sure what to check for.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: **[Can't find an input type=image value in $_POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681837/cant-find-an-input-type-image-value-in-post)**

Answer (score 0):

You could also have name for input type image.

```
<input type="image" name="iamge" src="somehting.jpg" alt="Buy Now" title=" Buy Now " id="addPartBtn">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works

```
<input type="image" name="iamge" src="somehting.jpg" alt="Buy Now" title=" Buy Now "          id="addPartBtn">

if(isset($_POST["iamge_x"]) && isset($_POST["iamge_y"]))
{
// then write your code
}
```