# Using image on login button

Tags: image, button, authentication

I have the following code sample login.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Modul 15 - Membuat Otentikasi User</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Form Login</h2>
Anda belum terdaftar sebagai user ?
[ <a href="register.php">Daftar sekarang</a>]
<br /><br />
<form action="do_login.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>ID User</td>
    <td><input type="textfield" name="id" maxlength="15" size="25" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="pwd" maxlength="15" size="25" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="image" src="login_btn.png" name="login" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the code for handle the process of login as do_login.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Modul 15 - Membuat Otentikasi User</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login'])) 
{
$id = $_POST['id'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
$database = "dbxxxxxx";
$hostname = "172.xx.xx.xx";
$port = "50000";

$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=$database;" .
"HOSTNAME=$hostname;PORT=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$id;PWD=$pwd;";
$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');
if ($conn) 
{
    echo "Connection succeeded.";
    db2_close($conn);
}
else 
{
    echo "Connection failed.";
}
}
else
{
echo "Login variable not set !!!";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The code always returns "**Login variable not set !!!**". Why does this happen? Are there something wrong with my codes ? Can someone help me please ...

Answer (score 2):

This is being returned because you're not actually posting 'login', as it does not have a value - try adding `value="1"` to the image button. Furthermore, it is not `input type="textfield"` but rather `input type="text"`.

Comment: The login variable will get posted, it just doesn't have a value. Try `<input type="image" src="login_btn.png" name="login" value="1" />`.

Comment: Thanks for the note on that @RayViljoen

Answer (score 0):

When you are using

```
 <input type="image" name="login">
```

there is actually 2 parameters sent, which is login_x and login_y

i've tried replacing

```
if (isset($_POST['login']))
```

using:

```
if(isset($_POST['login_x'], $_POST['login_y']))
```

It works just fine! You can read it more here: [Can't find an input type=image value in $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681837/cant-find-an-input-type-image-value-in-post)